# iOS7 How can I step aside from Navigation Control?

Tags: ios, iphone

**Brief Explanation:**

> View 1(Navigation Controlled) has a "add new object" button A.
>
> When click button A, it will move to View 2 (Navigation controlled and has back to view 1 button on the top with "< View 1")
>
> View 2 has a "Save object" button B, which I will add a new object into View 1's NSMutableArray.
>   However, when I click button B, it will go to View 1 with "< View 2" back button on the top of navigation bar even though it's the root navigation view.
>
> On storyboard, button A and B action is as push.

**Question**

How can I get out of this navigation movement?
Is there a way I can direct to button B action to a certain view? Without navigation back bar automatically added on top?

[image: View1]

[image: View2]

[image: View1 again]

Answer (score 0):

The action for button B shouldn't be a push since you want to go back to the first controller. When you want to go back to the previous controller, you either should use the default back button in the navigation bar, or if you have a custom button, you should have `popViewControllerAnimated:` as its action.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, Button B(save) shouldn't be doing "go back" action since I want to have a "go back" button which automatically shown on the top already. I will look into popViewControllerAnimated.